# How to set space between two flexbox

Tags: angular-material

I am using material design flexbox layout and in a box, I have two boxes. I create on jsfiddle, to clarify what I mean:

[Angular Material app](http://jsfiddle.net/kostonstyle/emnsyrrd/3/)

I want to set between these boxes a space

```
<div flex layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
            <md-toolbar flex="15">
                 <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools">
                    <span>Home</span>
                  </h2>

            </md-toolbar>
                <!--How to set space between -->
            <md-toolbar>
                 <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools" layout-align="end center">
                    <span>Sign Up</span>
                    <span>Sign In</span>
                  </h2>

            </md-toolbar>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you need is 'layout-margin'
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options

```
<div layout="row" layout-margin>
  <div flex>Parent layout and this element have margins.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

For those interested in a solution using [Angular Flex Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout), you can achieve this with [fxLayoutGap directive](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxLayoutGap-API).

### Without fxLayoutGap

```
<div fxLayout="row">
   <div>1. One</div> <div>2. Two</div> <div>3. Three</div> <div>4. Four</div>
</div>
```

[image]

### With fxLayoutGap

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px">
  <div>1. One</div> <div>2. Two</div> <div>3. Three</div> <div>4. Four</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it much simpler:

```
<md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <span>Home</span>
        <span flex></span>
        <div>
            <span>Sign Up</span>
            <span>Sign In</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

You can insert flexible element  between HOME and SIGNUP  elements and it will fill the space between them.